# Keep settings across projects in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I like to activate a couple of settings in WebStorm (2016.2) that are not by default:
 - Projet View > "Autoscroll to Source" and "Autoscroll from Source"
 - Terminal > Uncheck "Pinned Mode"
 - etc...

Each time I open a new project, I have to change them manually.

Is there a way to tell WebStorm to keep these settings across projects?

Comment: I do not believe that there is clear option for all. The best I can think of (which should do the job -- well, seems to do for me at least in regards to tool window positions) is: 1) Configure desired options in one project and use `Window | Store Current Layout as Default` 2) Create new project -- these default settings should be used; if not -- use `Window | Restore Default Layout` 3) For existing projects -- try the aforementioned `Window | Restore Default Layout`

Comment: Awesome, thanks LazyOne, I didn't know about this "Store Current Layout as Default".